# Prevent NGINX from serving local index.html instead of passing to proxied server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Found other similar questions, but none seem to work in my circumstance.

I am attempting to proxy from NGINX to an IIS server which is hosting an archived website in its entirety.  The site is coded with some hard index.html links and I don't want to go in and modify the site at all.

Any time the site is called with the /index.html in the URL directly it appears that NGINX is not proxying the location, but instead serving out a local index.html page.

Additionally, I am trying to default instead of to the index.html page when no page is entered (i.e. domain only) instead to pass to a default.htm page (set as default in IIS) which provides a disclaimer page that will require reading before continuing on to the original index.html of the website.

This is my nginx configuration file for the site.  I do not want to change my overall structure around because it is what multiple sites use.  I need a solution that I can add in.

```
upstream my_backend {
        server 10.10.10.102:1011;
        include snippets/shared_upstream_settings.conf;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name server.mydomain.com;

        include snippets/shared_server_proxy_settings.conf;

        location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://my_backend;
        }

        location / {
                satisfy any;
                allow 10.16.0.0/24;
                deny all;
                auth_basic "Authorized Users Only";
                auth_basic_user_file secure/.htpasswd;
                auth_request /auth-1;
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }
```

(I don't believe any of the includes should matter for this particular issue)

This configuration works for about 15 other sites I have, but none of them apparently have a hardcoded index.html.  Until today I never realized that NGINX will not proxy a direct link to index.html.  So I need to either disable or work around that "feature" as well as direct no indicated pages to the disclaimer page.

thanks

Comment: Replace the `try_files $uri @proxy;` line with `proxy_pass http://my_backend;`, there is no need for a separate `location @proxy` block. If you want to keep the second `location` block, change the `try_files` statement to `try_files __nonexistent__ @proxy;`

Comment: Thank you Richard.  I realize that in this structure the @proxy block is superfluous, but as I mentioned I am trying to maintain a consistent structure with other configs which use it.

I tried the "__nonexistent__" option and that appears to work great.  Even with the knowledge of this now I am still able to find any information on this parameter in the documentation.  Do you know where it is referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$uri` argument in your `try_files` statement instructs Nginx to test for the existence of a file before branching to the `@proxy` block. There exists a local `index.html` file that satisfies that test.

You have two options:

---

Replace the `try_files $uri @proxy;` line with `proxy_pass http://my_backend;` as there is no need for a separate `location @proxy` block.

---

Or:

If you want to keep the second location block, change the `try_files` statement to:

```
try_files __nonexistent__ @proxy;
```

`try_files` [requires a minimum of two arguments](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). All arguments before the final argument are filenames to be tested. `__nonexistent__` is just one such name that probably does not exist on your file system (and also helps to document the author's intent).